# Why Garbage Collection freezes app?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, picasso

I am using Picassso android library to load images in a big list of images.
When I scroll down app freezes on relatively regular intervals.

In log I see lots of lines like this :

```
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 172K, 5% free 164195K/171316K, paused 365ms, total 366ms
```

I checked other photo gallery apps, they have similar GC_FOR_ALLOC lines in log, but they scroll smoooth.

How can I prevent garbage collection from freezing my UI thread?

The funny point is this is not happening on Nexus 7 ( Lollipop), just happens on Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8, OS 4.4.2

Comment: you may enable the logging in `Picasso` and see what causes that. Use `setIndicatorsEnabled(boolean)` and `setLoggingEnabled(boolean)`

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of Picasso *supports the pause/resume loading feature*, which is especially handy when you have a big list of images.

It works on a tag-basis, so you can call `Picasso.with(context).pauseTag(tag)` and Picasso.with(context).resumeTag()` to respectively stop loading (when the user is scrolling) and resume loading (when scrolling has stopped or when the user is touch-scrolling).

Something like this should definitely improve the scrolling experience:

```
private String scrollTag = "scrollTag";

...

listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE || scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).resumeTag(scrollTag);
        } else {
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).pauseTag(scrollTag);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {}
};
```

In addition, be sure that you're either calling `fit()` or `resize(w, h)` + `centerCrop()` or `centerInside()`, so that Picasso scales the image according to the desired size.

Comment: Tried this pause and resume feature, still have problems on OSs lower than 5.

Comment: Please, consider posting the code that you're using to load the images then.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there try using Universal Image Loader instead, by default it caches images and is highly customizable see link below:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Tried Universal Image Loader right now, still same problem.

Comment: Look on customizing the memory/disk cache, would it be possible to see your code?